# How to do Base64 decode and Lower in single mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I am stucked in one of MySQl query. I want two process on one field. Let say the field is named 'title'. Now title has BASE64_encoded data in it. Now I want to fetch all the data in lower case with mysql. I tried below code. but I didnt get my result. Hope you help me.

```
SELECT LOWER(FROM_BASE64(title)) as title FROM my_table;
```

I know, both are working individually. but not together. Now How can I do both process in one mysql.

Answer (score 6):

I found solution.

```
SELECT LOWER(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(title) USING latin1)) as title FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT LOWER(X) as title FROM (select FROM_BASE64(title) as X from my_table);
```

Comment: Yes this is one of solution. Thank you. But can we have another option?

Comment: @RonakP:- Not sure but did you try to use: `SELECT FROM_BASE64(LOWER(title)) as title FROM my_table;`

Comment: No This will change value.

Comment: @RonakP:- Yes this is what I suspected. I think you need to go with the query pasted above or you may wait for some time to get some other alternative. Happy coding :)